# How to run sonatype nexus on aws ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, nexus

I need to put sonatype nexus3 up on AWS. Following an old tutorial for nexus 2, I was led to try this on EC2. What I'm currently trying is an instance with a security group that allows inbound requests from anywhere on ports 80,8080,22,4000,443, and 8081. I'm using a Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type instance. I install docker using the instructions from here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html#install_docker. I then simply use the official docker image from here https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/ with the following command.

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus sonatype/nexus3
```

Using `docker ps` I can confirm that this seems to be running. When I try to connect to the provided public DNS url ending with amazonaws.com on port 8081, I simply get connection refused. Same thing on port 80 or any of the other ports and the same thing when I add `/nexus` to the end of the URL.

Attempting the quick test that documentation for this image suggests:

```
>curl -u admin:admin123 http://localhost:8081/service/metrics/ping
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Using the exact same docker command on my local machine (OS X) I am able to access nexus on localhost. Why can't I get this working?

Comment: Just an idea: Assuming you can access on port 22 (ssh), maybe you have a firewall running on the EC2 instance that blocks all ports. If so, open them up and try again. Your setup should work.

Comment: @EldadAK Hmm i was under the impression that setting the security group was how i made sure the ports weren't blocked. Also note that this is a fresh instance and i've only done to the instance what i described in the post. Where would i check firewall settings?

Comment: Connection refused implies you are getting past the ec2 security group to the host but the host or container is not listening on the port. Your port mapping looks ok so try running `docker exec <containerid> ss -lntp` to see what is listening in the running container. `docker logs <containerid>` should show you any errors.

Comment: @Matt The logs seem to have some random exceptions in them http://pastebin.com/TxBcLVAK

Comment: @Matt and the exec command seems to fail with: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: \"ss\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: I just got this to work with an unofficial image, so i think the image is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to have been with Sonatype's official image. [This image](https://hub.docker.com/r/clearent/nexus/) which works the exact same way, works perfectly with the exact same process.